# Lua ordered table iteration

Tags: lua, lua-table

I need to iterate through Lua table in order which it's created. I found this article - http://lua-users.org/wiki/SortedIteration
But it doesn't seems like working:

```
function __genOrderedIndex( t )
local orderedIndex = {}
for key in pairs(t) do
    table.insert( orderedIndex, key )
end
table.sort( orderedIndex )
return orderedIndex
end

function orderedNext(t, state)
-- Equivalent of the next function, but returns the keys in the alphabetic
-- order. We use a temporary ordered key table that is stored in the
-- table being iterated.

key = nil
--print("orderedNext: state = "..tostring(state) )
if state == nil then
    -- the first time, generate the index
    t.__orderedIndex = __genOrderedIndex( t )
    key = t.__orderedIndex[1]
else
    -- fetch the next value
    for i = 1,table.getn(t.__orderedIndex) do
        if t.__orderedIndex[i] == state then
            key = t.__orderedIndex[i+1]
        end
    end
end

if key then
    return key, t[key]
end

-- no more value to return, cleanup
t.__orderedIndex = nil
return
end

function orderedPairs(t)
    return orderedNext, t, nil
end
```

Here is the usage example:

```
t = {
['a'] = 'xxx',
['b'] = 'xxx',
['c'] = 'xxx',
['d'] = 'xxx',
['e'] = 'xxx',
}


for key, val in orderedPairs(t) do
   print(key.." : "..val)
end
```

I'm getting an error:

> attempt to call field 'getn' (a nil value)

What is the problem?

Comment: Not an answer, but an excellent resource: (http://devdocs.io/lua/)

Answer (score 4):

`table.getn` has been removed since Lua 5.1, it's replaced by the `#` operator.

Change `table.getn(t.__orderedIndex)` to `#t.__orderedIndex`.

Comment: And what if I need to iterate in order in which it's created. Is it possible?

Comment: The order is unspecified. Ask a new question if you've got a new one.

Comment: Thank you very much, new question is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32451755/is-there-a-way-to-iterate-through-lua-dictionary-in-order-that-its-created . Would really appreciate your help.